# What is the boolean expression?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I think it might involve creating a logic table first. Please help!

An elevator has the following sensors:

G - The gate is closed
L - The elevator is loaded.
B - The elevator is in demand.
M - The elevator is moving.

Give a Boolean expression of an alarm signal, A(G, B, L, M), so that A is true if (a) the gate is not closed and the elevator is moving, or (b) the elevator is moving but not in demand or loaded, or (c) the gate is not closed and the elevator is loaded and moving, or (d) the elevator is not loaded, not moving, and in demand.

Answer (score 1):

> A is true if (a) the gate is not closed and the elevator is moving, or (b) the elevator is moving but not in demand or loaded, or (c) the gate is not closed and the elevator is loaded and moving, or (d) the elevator is not loaded, not moving, and in demand.

This sentence is essentially a Boolean expression already -- all you need to do is translate it from words into symbols. Here's a start:

```
A is true if (a) the gate is not closed and the elevator is moving,
A     =      (   ¬   G                   ∧      M                 )

          or (b) the elevator is moving but not in demand or loaded…
          ∨  (       M                   ∧  ¬  ( B        ∨  L   ) )…
```